# Running a single line of code in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm coming from RStudio, so forgive my naievete.

In RStudio it's really nice to be able to run lines by simply pressing Ctrl+Enter on the line. This sends the line of code directly to the console, which makes building functions really easy because you can work through each line to check for problems. However, in Pycharm this doesn't appear to be a feature; instead, you select with a mouse and run code (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/loading-code-from-editor-into-console.html).

This seems like a cumbersome way to write code. Is there a way to run a single like of code like in RStudio?

Comment: The trick is to press `Alt` + `Shift` + `E` all at the same time. I can't believe they made it this hard; running code must be the most common thing people do in PyCharm. Don't you wish PyCharm was half as convenient as RStudio?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will execute in console.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will let you search for hotkeys.

Comment: Thanks, but don't I have to select the code first, then hit atl+shift+e?

Comment: No, you can simply place your cursor in the line. It will also move the cursor to the next line if nothing is selected

Comment: Is it possible to execute code that is split over multiple lines (i.e. a `for` loop or a call to a function that does not fit in a single line) without having to select it? thanks

Comment: I have the same question, would be very helpful to know!

Comment: I have the same question as @davide  also. This is something that is also very easy in RStudio, but not in pycharm.

Comment: @davide The closest I've found so far is to shift select the lines starting from wherever your cursor is (doesn't matter if you select all the code as long as you have at least part of each line selected) and then press the shortcut for extend line selection and then run selected code

Comment: @Vedda if you dont select the code it simply runs the current line where the cursor is. I select code if want to run a commented line or multiple lines. That's infact is a cool feature. Imagine how many times you commented out and uncommented print code you added for debugging or initial stages of  developing that piece of code?

Answer (score 30):

It is also possible to change the key combination to your liking.

For example, if you used to work with `ctrl + enter` in R, you can change it in:

`File -> Settings -> Keymap - Other -> Execute selection in Python Console`

Comment: I cannot find `Execute selection in Python Console` in Data Spell (should be the same as PyCharm. Currently my action is Alt+Shift+E and I would like to change it to Ctrl+Enter

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in my case. Also coming from R Studio. I removed the ALT + SHIFT + E option and replaced it with CTRL + enter, but doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: There is a message saying _Already assigned to:_ then the list of the corresponding action. How to overcome this ?

Answer (score 10):

Currently the best option:

1. First download the free plugin [***`Python Smart Execute`***](https://github.com/guoci/pycharm-smart-execute)
2. Use the key combination `OPTION + SHIFT + A`
3. If preferred change the key combination to `COMMAND + ENTER`

Despite not skipping blank lines, it pretty much resembles the way you can execute code in RStudio

Comment: How to change the key combination?

Comment: In MacOS: Preferences > Keymap > Plugins > Python Smart Execute. Right click "Smart execute selection in console" and click "Add Keyboard Shortcut".

Answer (score 2):

You can also look into `"Evaluate Expression"` option, which let's you run code in the current scope while debugging, it's usefull for lookups and modification in runtime.

Here is link to IDEA, but it's the same with PyCharm:
(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html)

Answer (score 2):

In PyCharm 2022.2 (not sure about other versions):

File -> Settings -> Keymap -> Plugins -> Python Community Edition -> Execute Selection in Python Console -> Change this to `Ctrl + ENTER` -> Accept prompt's suggestion to clear this shortcut for other commands -> Apply

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is about PyCharm. But for people who came here from **Visual Studio Code** world and wonder is there such feature. It is simple as <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.