# Is there a feature in PyCharm similar to RStudio's Global Environment and partial code execution?

Tags: python, variables, pycharm, rstudio, execute

In RStudio there's the ability to execute specific lines of code from the script, while IDE holds the variables and their values at the Global Environment.

I am looking for similar feature/s in PyCharm.
I am not sure how can i execute specific lines of code from my script, While the variables that already created or altered in the previous executes and their values still exists.

Is it even possible? How?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637853/running-a-single-line-of-code-in-pycharm/49637877#49637877

And yes, pycharm will keep your variables

Comment: @krflol Is there an indication that my lines are still being executed, like a simple Run?

Comment: You can tell if your `In[number]:' or '>>>' havent appeared back (depending on your environment). Also, if you try to execute in console while something else is running, youll get an error like "Previous command is still running"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a single line of code in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637853/running-a-single-line-of-code-in-pycharm)